# проблема импорта функции из файла

Tags: python, импорт

я написал простую функцию которая возвращает то что я написал, она находится в другом файле я вроде бы импортирую правильно но возникает ошибка ImportError. У меня есть функция aaaa в ttt.py, я пытаюсь ее импортировать в progect.py, но при написании from ttt import aaaa у меня возникает ошибка: from ttt import aaaa
ImportError: cannot import name 'aaaa' from 'ttt' как ее исправить? Я использую python 3.11.6 [image: вроде бы на картинке все понятно?]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120) Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: я знаю, но я думаю картинка с ошибкой будет более наглядно понять ошибку, чем просто ее описать словами

Comment: Ну, во-первых все-таки перенесите текст кода и ошибки в вопрос. Картинку можете не удалять, какую-то пользу она все же приносит. Во-вторых. Проверьте, что aaaa написано у вас на одном и том же языке (не английскими и русскими буквами), так бывает. И кстати, слово project пишется не через g.

Comment: И так и не добавил текстом. Печально.

Comment: я бы добавил, но я удалил проект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте текстом  код и ошибку, это облегчит труд отвечающих.

```
import ttt
print(ttt.aaaa('ddd'))
```

Comment: это помогло, но у меня остался почему все же не работает from ttt import aaaa?

Comment: import использует модули, а from использует пакеты. Я вам предлагаю почитать руководство, а что не понятно, спросить в вопросе.

Comment: почему стала возникать ошибка: print(ttt.aaaa(a))

AttributeError: module 'ttt' has no attribute 'aaaa'

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос с описанием кода и приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: все тоже самое с вашим изменениями, просто когда я запускаю код ввожу имя и выскакивает ошибка